# Call a JS function every time my view is rendered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a JS function that is only called when I refresh my view. I'd like it to be called every time I navigate to that view, which is not happening.

```
<div class="featured__section__jobs">
  <% @jobs.each do |job|%>
    <div class="job__card job__card__listing">
      <h3 class="job__title"><%=link_to job.job_title, job_path(job)%></h3>
      <span class="company__name"><%=link_to job.company_name, job.user%></span>
      <p class="job__specifics__description"><%= job.job_description%></p>
      <div class="job__specifics">
        <span class="job__specifics__span"><%= job.job_type %></span>
        <span class="job__specifics__span"><%= job.job_location %></span>
        <span class="job__specifics__span"><%= job.job_location %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  const truncatedStrings = document.getElementsByClassName('job__specifics__description')
  console.log(truncatedStrings)
  for(let i = 0; i<truncatedStrings.length; i++) {
    const str = truncatedStrings[i].innerText
    const array = str.trim().split(' ');
    const ellipsis = array.length > 100 ? '...' : '';
    truncatedStrings[i].innerText = array.slice(0, 100).join(' ') + ellipsis
  }
</script>
```

It's probably a rookie mistake. Any help shall be apprecaited

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "navigate to that view"? How are you navigating to the view? How is the view created? The version of Rails and the view mechanism in use matters.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this with javascript in the first place? It would be way easier to just write a helper method in Ruby to do this on the server side.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have links in my navbar that navigate to different pages (views) and these views have JS functions that will only run when I refresh the page. I'm using Rails 7.